# ssh: Could not resolve hostname keygen: Temporary failure in name resolution как исправить на ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

Помогите сгенерировать приватный и публичный ssh ключи для моей виртуальной ОС. Сижу на Ubuntu 22.04. Все делаю по [этой](https://loftschool.com/blog/posts/78-nastroyka-dostupa-po-ssh-k-neskolkim-profilyam-na-github-s-odnogo-kompyutera/) статье. Застрял на первом же шаге.

Ввожу `sudo ssh keygen` в терминале - получаю ошибку:

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname keygen: Temporary failure in name resolution

Искал решение, попытался исправить. В `/etc/resolv.conf` Поменял мой DNS сервер на Google сервера (8.8.8.8 и 1.1.1.1)
Затем командой `sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service` перезапустил сервис. `hostname` В файлике hosts тоже правильно указан. В чем еще может быть проблема?

Comment: `ssh-keygen` через дефис и **без** sudo. Читайте внимательно.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo ssh keygen` -- это команда означает, что ты хочешь подключиться под администратором на хост с именем `keygen`. Этот хост должен быть либо в DNS твоего провайдера, либо в `/etc/hosts`, либо в `$HOME/.ssh/config`.

Он может выглядеть примерно так:

```
$HOME/.ssh/config:
    Host keygen
    Hostname 192.168.1.1
    User ubuntu
    Port 22
    IdentityFIle ~/.ssh/my_private_key_ed25519
```

Проще всего сделать себе новый ключ такой командой:

```
ssh-keygen -q -t ed25519 -N '' -C "My key $(date -I)" -f ~/.ssh/my_private_key_ed25519
```